# How to check presence and datatype of database table columns at run time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to check the *presence* of a database table column and the *datatype* (eg: `String`, `Integer`, ...) of that column for a given model class. That is, I am implementing a Ruby module inside the `lib` directory with a method to which it is passed a model class (eg: `Article`) and I would like to verify just some conditions on certain related database table columns, *nothing more*.

In my module method I tried to use the [column_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists?) method as the following

```
module MyModule
  def check_column(model_class)
    table = model_class.to_s.tableize

    unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.column_exists?(table.to_sym, :title)
      raise ...
    end
  end
end
```

but without success: the (strange) outputted error related to the [column_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists?) method is something like this

```
Mysql2::Error: Table '<MY_APP_NAME>_development.<A_TABLE_NAME>/<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>/<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `<A_TABLE_NAME>/<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>/<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>`
```

What I should make to properly check *presence* and *datatype* of database table columns at run time?

Comment: Do you expect your database to be changing underneath your application? The database should be static and its tables, fields and field-types be pre-determined, either through a migration or because it's legacy. Why won't you know ahead of time what type a field is? Any ORM has to know the table names, field names and types in order to work correctly. Both ActiveRecord and Sequel check the schema after they connect, so it's a case of asking them. Sequel makes it easy to find that stuff out so I'm sure ActiveRecord does too. But the question remains, why do you need to check?

Comment: @the Tin Man - (1) **You**: "Do you expect your database to be changing underneath your application?". **I**: No, I don't. (2) **You**: "[...] why do you need to check?". **I**: I wrote that in the question: "I would like to verify just some conditions on certain related database table columns, *nothing more*".

Comment: Before your application starts you should know everything about the database, so, without even querying it you know the datatypes, field widths, field names, etc. You shouldn't need to check anything. If you do, there is something wrong with the data validation or the system design.

Comment: @the Tin Man - You are right, but for my needs database table columns are checked when the application starts in developer mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` to send queries directly to the DBM.

From that you could ask the DBM to describe a particular table, then parse the fields to find out anything about the datatypes.

Comment: Can you make an example on how to properly use the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` in my case?